# TikTok captcha loading undefined in selenium chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, tiktok

I'm attempting to create a web scraper to scrape TikTok videos using selenium with chromedriver.

When navigating to TikTok, they show a page with a captcha slider, but recently this page has not been loading properly and I just get a blank page that says 'undefined'

The page includes this html:

```
<p class=\"page-desc\" id=\"verifyEle\">undefined</p>
```

When the page loads properly it contains the picture-slider captcha

I have tried changing and disabling proxy, updating chrome driver and chrome version, as well as various chrome options.

What could be causing the captcha page to break? Has anyone else encountered something like this before?

Comment: It seems that the captha works as intended, to defeat bots

Comment: @Robert Smith Read [tour] and [mcve] and edit your post accordingly